# Power Automate: Get internal ID (numeric) of item

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, flow, power-automate, id

When I want to reference individual items of a list, I can use the ID easily.
IDs are assigned for new items sequentially and unique.

However if I save an ID into a string variable to use it for other purposes I get a gibberish long thing which apparently contains the ID of the list and the internal ID.

e.g.:

```
e2db568a-8e97-4f73-b6f5-f9b395f8870c: 3
```

Of course I could **split()** the string to get rid of the list part, but it is perhaps a unsafe way not knowing the structure of the gibberish.

There must be a more easy way to access the integer. I assume I can access it directly by some ()?[] trickery.

Comment: What is the trigger of your flow? how you are setting value of variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using any one of the triggers of [SharePoint Connector triggers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sharepointonline/#triggers), you can easily access list item ID using below expression:

```
@{triggerOutputs()?['body/ID']}
```

Also, you can select the ID property from **dynamic content** (as you are already doing it). Both above cases working perfectly fine for me while storing item ID in **string** variable.

**Flow**:

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

---

I have also tested using **integer** variable & it is giving results same as above screenshots.

Comment: perhaps I have to copy it into a variable first. I will check that along with your other comment.

Comment: Yes, use initialize variable action to save the ID. If string variable is not working then try using "integer" variable.